# How to get text rendered in the cells?

Tags: grid, jqwidget

How can I get text rendered in the cells? I have tried the following :

[1] `$(gridId).jqxGrid('getcellvaluebyid', rowID, columnFields[j])`

[2] `$(gridId).jqxGrid('getcelltextbyid', rowID, columnFields[j])`

However, I only get the actual values of the cells like flags and status codes instead of the actual flag names and status names rendered on the specific cell (using cells renderer).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by creating an Array variable and caching the cellsrenderer result using that Array. After that you can access the rendered cell content using your Array and your array keys.